# Make an image color (not bitmap) transparant

Tags: image

I'm drawing an image on a PictureBox using Graphics.DrawImage() method. The background of the drawn image should be transparant so that it's not drawn on top of the the other things made by grapics. The code looks like this:

```
Image Icon = Image.FromFile(@"C:\\Dieroller\Die Icons\d4.jpg");

//Icon.SetColorToTransparant(White); //This is what I which would work.

Graphics.DrawImage(Icon, Location);
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: uhhhhhh, what language?

Comment: Given that your file is a JPEG image, instead of setting a color to be transparent, you'll need to remove pixels of that color from the image. If the image were PNG then you could use the alpha channel.

Comment: Oh, it's C# express 2010. I can easily make it PNG, but then how do I set an alpha channel. I don't know the methods or syntax

Comment: Ah PNG did the trick! thanks!

Comment: Okay another related question. Can you somehow change the overall color of the image. Like make it darker or more blue etc?